# how to read and add stirng and write back each line in python ?

Tags: python, windows-7

I need to open a file to read each line, then add a string at the end of each line.
And then, write back the new line the opened file.

```
    number = 0 
    with open("test_openFile.txt", "r+b") as the_file:
    for line in the_file:
        print (line)
        type(line)
        line = line.strip('\n') + "\t" + str(number)
        number += 1
        the_file.write(line)
```

But, I got:

```
  line = line.strip('\n')
  TypeError: Type str doesn't support the buffer API
```

Any help would be appreciated !

Comment: Are you intentionally opening this in binary mode?

Answer (score 2):

Try it like this

```
import fileinput

for line in fileinput.input("myfile.txt", inplace=1):
    print line.strip() + " a cool string"
```

that will add " a cool string" to the end of every line

Comment: +1 for `fileinput`. But the format string seems to serve no purpose.

Comment: You're right it doesn't, I kept having difficulties getting the newline characters to play nice... fixed.

Comment: The newlines should be written back automatically, if you want to suppress the newlines add a comma to the end of the print statement.

Comment: @johnthexiii I think he means "How do I write the newly created line back into a file", not "How do I write a newline character into a file".

Comment: @user2420472, fileinput takes all your print statements and writes them to the file.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import os
fd_r=open('whatever.txt','r').readlines()
fd_w=open('whatever.txt','w')

for line in fd_r:
    line=line.strip()+" adding 1234"
    fd_w.write(line+"\n")
fd_w.close()
```

This will append the string " adding 1234" to every line.

Comment: if file size is very large, fd_r (a string) will be very large, the memory usage is not efficient, right ? thanks !

Comment: Yeah.. if memory is the concern then use fileinput which will create a temp file write the modified lines to it and end will move the temp file with original filename. you have to choose memory or the temp file depending on your requirement.

Comment: it depends on the size of temp file, after all writing is done, the temp file will overwrite the original file ? right ?

Comment: Thats correct. You need to set bufsize=0 so that while creating a temp file buffer is not used. Anyway fileinput sets the bufsize=0 by default. You should use fileinput as long as you have concerns with buffer/memory.